# Elasticsearch Query Sanitization & Security

Tags: security, elasticsearch, sanitization

I have a dataset hosted in Elasticsearch that I would like to expose to my end users for searching. Basically, I would like to have a search box in my application that would let users write queries that I can then run on Elasticsearch cluster.

Elasticsearch recommends that [simple query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) be used whenever we are dealing with user inputs that can't be trusted. This is not optimal as I would like to retain the attribute based search that the default Elasticsearch queries can handle.

Example indexed document:

```
{
    "account_id": "1357983",
    "first_name": "godzilla",
    "age": 36"
}
```

I would like to support queries like the following to my end users:

```
# This is not possible with Simple Query String as far as I understand
first_name:"godzilla" AND age:36
```

I understand that security & performance are 2 main reasons not running user entered queries directly on the cluster.

Question:

1. What are some steps I can take to protect the cluster against malicious(?) queries?
2. Is there some kind of sanitization step I can run on user entered queries before I run them on Elasticsearch?
3. Performance issues aside, are there any security implications?

Things I am already doing:

1. The search results are never directly returned to users. Searches are only used to identify documents that have a unique ID associated. These IDs are then used to find the actual records in a RDBMS systems and then returned to users. Only those records that actually belong to the user are returned to the end user.
2. Every query has an explicit timeout set to 5 seconds.
3. Every query has the size attribute configured to 20 so that only the top 20 matching records are returned(this is enough for my use case).
4. expand_wildcards is set to false
5. (Naive approach that I have not tried yet) - Strip out all wildcard expressions(`*` and `?`) from query before running the query. Show an error message to user if these terms are used. I am only interested in supporting exact matches for now.
6. Is there a way to disable regex, fuzziness & wildcards so that only exact matches are returned so that performance does not take a hit when queries like `/.*/` are run?
7. Disabled Expensive queries [as defined here](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-allow-expensive-queries/)

Apart from the above mentioned points, what else can I do to protect the ES cluster from a Security & Performance perspective?